# number pair's in the self-root function $f(x) = x^{1/x}$

Tags: number-theory

in the self-root function $f(x) = x^{1/x}$ the output is in pairs of numbers i.e.

$f(2) = f(4)$ , the inputs are 2 apart producing the same output , 
the square root 2 is equal to the 4th root of 4

$f(e) = f(e)$ , this pair is 0 apart , e being the zenith of the function

so my question is what pair of inputs are 1 apart and does this problem have a name. I seem to remember been asked this question about 35 years ago !

thanks

Comment: Easy enough to solve $(x+1)^x=x^{x+1}$ numerically...wolfram alpha gives $x\sim 2.29317$.  Don't know if that number is easily expressed in terms of basic operations on familiar numbers.

Comment: As for the name, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FoiasConstant.html

Answer (score 3):

The function $x^{1/x}$  grows initially, upto $e$ . Then it decreases continuously asymptomatically reaching $1$. At a value of around $2.3$, you get the function to be $1.436$ which is same as the one at $3.3$ . So, the answer to your question is approximately $(2.3,3.3)$ There is no name to the function as far as I know.

Comment: @YuriyS You are right. Thank you. edited.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers guys,

yeah it's a pity about the name, I guess it might have been some other question, 35 years is a long time ago,

anyway here is the answer, 
the pair is: 3.2931662874118610315080282912508058644 and 2.293166...
whose self-root is 1.4360782754785005923310883850289

I believe it to be an important number.

thanks for all your answers