# Is there an exact form for the solution for $x$ to $(\frac{1}{x})^{(\frac{1}{x})}=1-(\frac{1}{x})$?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, recreational-mathematics

The solution for x in this the equation $(\cfrac1x)^{\cfrac1x}=1-\cfrac1x$ is approximately 3.29316628741186103150802829...

Other forms of this equation which have the same solution include :

$y^{y}=1-y$
, $\cfrac1y$ = x

(In which y is equal to 0.3036591270299660... for an extended decimal form try this link and expand the solution :
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5Ey%3D1-y

$x^\cfrac {x-1} x - x = -1$ (This is the first equation Wolfram Math Alpha gave me the actual approximate answer)

This number can also be described as $1/$ root of $x^x + x -1 = -1$

I find this problem very similar to this one where the same constants are used :
[number pair's in the self-root function $f(x) = x^{1/x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653833/number-pairs-in-the-self-root-function-fx-x1-x/1653854)

Related Equations that I think are also interesting :

$(\cfrac1a)^{\cfrac1a}=1+\cfrac1a$
(This one is about 0.562817451524631909792003735...)

$(\cfrac1b)^{\cfrac1b}=b+\cfrac1b$
(Approx. 0.609902981394622279977041843...)

$(\cfrac1c)^{\cfrac1c}=c-\cfrac1c$
(c ≈ 1.45799331624361272150026003...)

Is it possible to find an exact form for this solution and is there any significance to equations/solutions like this?

(If you want an extended decimal form for the 1st equation go to this link and expand the 'Numerical Solution')
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%28%28x+-+1%29%2Fx%29-x%3D-1

Answer (score 3):

There is no analytical solution for the equation
$$y^y=1-y$$ even using special functions.

We can make decent approximation considering that we look for the zero of function
$$f(y)=y\log(y)-\log(1-y)$$

Using Taylor expansion, we have
$$f(y)=y (\log (y)+1)+\frac{y^2}{2}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, the non-trivial solution is
$$y_0=2 W\left(\frac{1}{2 e}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

Now, iterating using Newton method, we have
$$y_{n+1}=\frac{(y_n-2) y_n+(y_n-1) \log (1-y_n)}{(y_n-2)+(y_n-1) \log (y_n)}$$ This can be considered as an explicit recurrence equation which, as shown below, converges very fast.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & y_n \\
 0 & \color{red}{0.3}14369902967628019173913392043 \\
 1 & \color{red}{0.303}893759613688751450583356220 \\
 2 & \color{red}{0.303659}245373552388724380071295 \\
 3 & \color{red}{0.303659127029996}192264680381756 \\
 4 & \color{red}{0.30365912702996605124501895}3168 \\
 5 & \color{red}{0.303659127029966051245018951213}
\end{array}
\right)$$